# Hide HTML5 audio player using javascript if dynamic audio src is not found or is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, audio

First Post on Stackoverflow so bear with me please. 
I have a JQMobile web app that is generating dynamic audio file links via JSON and appending the audio player per id. I am trying to hide the player when a src is not found.

The php/mysql/jqm scripting is working, I just cannot seem to get the if/else portion it always shows the player empty or not.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
var serviceURL = "http://localhost/Apps/services/";

$(document).on('pageshow', '#detailsPage', function(event) {
    var id = getUrlVars()["id"];
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getartist.php?id='+id, displayArtist);
});

function displayArtist(data) {
    var artistDetVal = data.item;
    console.log(artistDetVal);
    $('#artistDetPic').attr('src', 'pics/lg/' + artistDetVal.picture);
    $('#fullName').text(artistDetVal.firstName + ' ' + artistDetVal.lastName);
    $('#artistDetTitle').text(artistDetVal.bio);
    $('#city').text(artistDetVal.city);
    $('#audioBio').attr('src', 'audio/' + artistDetVal.audio) .detach().appendTo($("#audioPlayer"));
    }

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
</script>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

function displayArtist(data) {
var artistDetVal = data.item;
$('#audioBio').text(artistDetVal.audio);

if (artistDetVal.audio>0) {
    $("#audioPlayer").show();
    }
else {
    $("#audioPlayer").hide();
    }
  }
});
</script>

<audio id="audioPlayer" controls="controls"><source id="audioBio" src=""/></audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if your function `displayArtist` is being declared twice which is a "no-no". Also, the second declaration, which is the one which controls whether to show or hide the player, is never called.

Try putting the logic for showing/hiding the player in your first instance of `displayArtist` and removing the duplicate altogether.

```
function displayArtist(data) {
    var artistDetVal = data.item;
    console.log(artistDetVal);
    $('#artistDetPic').attr('src', 'pics/lg/' + artistDetVal.picture);
    $('#fullName').text(artistDetVal.firstName + ' ' + artistDetVal.lastName);
    $('#artistDetTitle').text(artistDetVal.bio);
    $('#city').text(artistDetVal.city);
    $('#audioBio').attr('src', 'audio/' + artistDetVal.audio).detach().appendTo($("#audioPlayer"));

    $('#audioBio').text(artistDetVal.audio);

    if (artistDetVal.audio>0) {
        $("#audioPlayer").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#audioPlayer").hide();
    }
}
```

Also, if `artistDetVal.audio` is a string you may want to use the condition `if(artistDetVal.audio.length > 0)`